# How to register Springs SIGTERM graceful shutdown synchronous method before PreDestroy?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Springs allows to register multiple pre-destroy hooks using `@PreDestroy` annotation which is useful to clear resources.
We have multiple different modules where each module is related to a different database connection. In each of those modules we define destroy method for each of such database connection using either `@Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")` or a separate method annotated with `@PreDestroy` for a more complex shutdown process.
We also have multiple modules related to endpoints implementations (like modules for `gRPC` endpoints, `GraphQL` endpoints, `REST` endpoints).
We want to add graceful shutdown process for applications using those endpoints. By graceful shutdown I mean the flow like below:

1. Shutdown endpoint servers first (i.e. reject any new connections, but await for the current connections to be finished). I.e. we need to shutdown and await for the shutdown process to be finished for the following endpoint servers: `gRPC`, `GraphQL`, `REST`.
2. Only after step `1.` is fully finished we should trigger beans destruction methods (i.e. methods annotated with `@PreDestroy` and specified via `destroyMethod`).

How to correctly inject specific hook which is called before all other hooks for SIGTERM signal?

P.S. I assume that we might be using `@PreDestroy` incorrectly because the functionality we are looking for is `@PrePreDestroy` which sounds silly.

Side note: `server.shutdown=graceful` isn't an option for us because we are using custom servers and not default embedded servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a little bit of experimenting I found out that `ApplicationListener` on `ContextClosedEvent` will always be executed before any `@PreDestroy` method or any bean's `destroyMethod` is called. I.e. `onApplicationEvent(ContextClosedEvent event)` is always called first.

An example is:

```
@Component
public class PriorityShutdownListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextClosedEvent> {
    
    @Autowired
    private Server grpcServer;
    
    /**
     * This blocking code will be executed before any 
     * @PreDestroy method or bean's `destroyMethod` is called.
     */
    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextClosedEvent event) {
        grpcServer.shutdown();
        // don't forget to await for existing
        // calls to finish before returning from this method
    }
}
```